# Why does a Perl script run during boot on CentOS not find certain modules?

Tags: linux, perl

I am currently trying to run a perl script at boot in a custom version of CENTOS.

I am doing so by calling it from an rc1 script, the call looks like this:

```
/mydirectory/myscript &
```

But I'm getting the error "Can't locate strict.pm in @INC"

This isn't specific to strict.pm, it throws that error at for whichever module is first on the use list. When I run the same command from the shell, however, it runs no problem.

So why is it that my perl script cannot find the modules during bootup?

Comment: Maybe the `@INC`, which comes from the environment, has not been built up.

Comment: Check `perl -e 'print "$_\n" for @INC'`, perhaps it is broken.

Comment: I ran that from the shell while the machine was on and got:



`/perl

/netfort/lib

/usr/local/lib64/perl5

/usr/local/share/perl5

/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl

/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl

/usr/lib64/perl5

/usr/share/perl5

.`

and then again while the machine was booting:


`/usr/local/lib64/perl5

/usr/local/share/perl5

/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl

/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl

/usr/lib64/perl5

/usr/share/perl5
.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the `@INC`, which comes from the environment, has not been built up. It needs the paths to its libraries.

You can either call it explicitly with the perl interpreter and the `-I` option, or set the `PERL5LIB` environment variable.

```
PERL5LIB='/usr/lib/perl5' /mydirectory/myscript &
```

If there are several folders, separate them with a colon `:`.

```
 PERL5LIB='/usr/lib/perl5:/tmp:/etc/lib/perl5' /mydirectory/myscript &
```

**Please note that I don't know where the lib dir is in your CentOS**, so I made that path up.

You can find out by printing `@INC` from a regular shell like this:

```
$ perl -E 'say for @INC'
```

Append all the paths it lists to the environment variable for the call you make in your rc1 script and it should work.

Comment: When checking my @INC at various times:

I ran that from the shell while the machine was on and got:



`/perl

/netfort/lib

/usr/local/lib64/perl5

/usr/local/share/perl5

/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl

/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl

/usr/lib64/perl5

/usr/share/perl5

.`

and then again while the machine was booting:


`/usr/local/lib64/perl5

/usr/local/share/perl5

/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl

/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl

/usr/lib64/perl5

/usr/share/perl5
.`


Should I just add what's missing from the second list?

Comment: I would start with that. But in any case having a directory twice doesn't really hurt. It might take a fraction longer if it looks there twice at startup, but I think that's neglegible.

Comment: It seemed like it had made progress, when I just included /perl, it gave an error saying it couldn't find another module (a custom one, which was located in /netfort/lib) but when I tried to include the two it went back to not finding strict.pm

Is this syntax correct for including multiple directories? Just a space between the two directory names `PERL5LIB='/perl /netfort/lib' /mydirectory/myscript &`

Comment: @Spellchamp see my edit. You need to use a colon `:`.

Comment: Perfect. I included all of the above directories just to be safe. Seems like The INC wasn't fully loaded by the time my script was called, or the two missing directories are part of this custom OS and are added to the INC at the end of the boot. Marked your answer as correct. Thank you very much.